# Why does compiling in -O2 crash my application but -O2 -fno-default-inline does not?

Tags: c++

I have a 3rd party lib called TheLib and my lib called MyLib

TheLib is compiled first with a Struct contained in a header file called variantmap.h.  This header contains 2 inline functions:

```
struct VariantMap {
    string name;
    map<string, Variant> children;
    bool isArray;

    VariantMap(VariantMap & variantMap) {
        name = variantMap.name;
        children = variantMap.children;
        isArray = variantMap.isArray;
    }

    VariantMap() {
        isArray = false;
    }
};
```

MyLib also compiles with the aforementioned header.

When I compile both libs with -O2 (optimization level) MyLib crashes, but if I compile MyLib with -O2 but without inline functions (i.e. -fno-default-inline), it does not???

The crash seems to occur on the assignment of the string name according to gdb?

Comment: So you've compiled MyLib `-O2 -fno-default-inline`, linked against TheLib compiled `-O2` and gotten a crash.  Have you tried compiling MyLib `-O2` and TheLib `-O2 -fno-default-inline`, or MyLib and TheLib both with `-O2 -fno-default-inline`?

Comment: Have you got the latest or the stable version of TheLib?

Comment: And what do you mean by "crash" specifically?  Segmentation fault?  I assume you mean the crash is in the first line of the copy constructor, which would imply that you're getting a bad argument.

Comment: Could you post the sample code which uses `VariantMap` and causes the crash?

Comment: Stylistically:  The struct appears to have some actual meaning as a coherent class, which means the data members probably should be private.  The copy constructor should have a `const VariantMap & variantMap` argument, and should use initialization rather than assignment.  If you've got a copy constructor, you should probably have a copy assignment operator.

Comment: The crash occurs here:

#8  0x00007f4e5f03f276 in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#9  0x00007f4e5fa867a0 in std::string::assign (this=0xec46d0, __str=<value optimized out>)
    at /home/bbazso/ThirdParty/sources/gcc-4.2.4/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:238

The code tries to free invalid memory.  Actually, according to valgrind the ptr it tries to free is in the application address space.  

It is possible that there is an optimization miss match between the libs and so I will recompile both the same and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not knowledgable of this problem on Linux (not enough experience on g++), but on Windows, it smells of incompatible runtimes mixed together, so I guess my answer could give you some limited insight...

At first guess, it could be because TheLib and MyLib have different implementation of the same functions.

If the "copy constructor" is inlined "into" your MyLib, then the code will use MyLib's compiled implementation of the copy constructor's code (i.e. the string assignment).

In the other hand, if the call to the copy constructor is not "inlined", then perhaps the call to the copy constructor will call the code compiled inside TheLib.

Imagine that the string assignation is different for whatever reason in TheLib and MyLib, then the crash is not a surprise. Perhaps MyLib is using a COW-enabled string, while TheLib uses a simpler string implementation.

Another possible source of problems would be different allocators. The malloc of TheLib is not the malloc of MyLib, and as such, trying to reallocate the string's buffer to accomodate the copy would lead to a crash, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good copy constructor:

```
  VariantMap(VariantMap & variantMap) {
        name = variantMap.name;
        children = variantMap.children;
        isArray = variantMap.isArray;
  }
```

Firstly, it does nothing the default copy constructor wouldn't do better, and secondly it does not have a const reference asa parameter. Also, as you provided a copy constructor, presumably you have an assignment op and  a destructor too? What do they look like? And lastly, is Variant (not VariantMap)  really copyable? Remember, the point the error appears to be at is usually just the place it manifests itself.

Comment: What would the const change such that it would not crash?

Comment: @user268822 Possibly nothing, but that is not a reason for not doing things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same versions of the C-Run-time in everything?  Some compiler suites add debug only information to header files (such as  for example).  If "TheLib" is compiled with the DEBUG pre-processor flag and you are compiling without, for example, then mismatches occur.  It may just be random that it crashes there.  Have you made sure that the data is correct the way that doesn't crash?

Answer (score 0):

You post does not contain enough information to determine the problem.  I suspect that the Variant class is not handling references properly.  The problem is probably only accidental to the optimazation level: one happens to fail silently while the other fails loudly.

Answer (score 0):

Bugs caused by optimisation settings are rare.  I'd bet somewhere in your program you are relying on undefined or unreliable behavior, which should crash all the time, but by chance does not crash with particular optimisation setting.  I'd say this is something else you're doing wrong, not your optimisation flags.

Comment: I agree with you, but it always crashes at the same location and if I change optimization levels it goes away.  I would love to be able to find it, but I tried tracking it down by doing a backtrace in gdb and valgrind and adding prints in the code and I have no idea why it's crashing.